# tidyverse-rename specific rows that contain string

Tags: r

I would like to rename all strings in column `NCBI_tax_id`  that contain `Adenoassociated` to `AD`. In my example the first three rows will become `AD`.

I tried this but not sure which `.fn` to use within rename:

```
rename_with(df, cols=NCBI_tax_id, contains("Adenoassociated"))
```

data:

```
 df <-     structure(list(NCBI_tax_id = c("Adenoassociated virus 2", "Adenoassociated virus3", 
"Adenoassociated virus8", "BK polyomavirus", "Camelpox virus", 
"Chimpanzee adenovirus Y25"), Sample_tax = c("ACTN01020001T_Adenoassociated virus 2", 
"ACTN01020001T_Adenoassociated virus3", "ACTN01020001T_Adenoassociated virus8", 
"ACTN01020001T_BK polyomavirus", "ACTN01020001T_Camelpox virus", 
"ACTN01020001T_Chimpanzee adenovirus Y25")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `rename_with` is for renaming columns. To recode your column you could do: `df %>% mutate(NCBI_tax_id = ifelse(grepl("Adenoassociated", NCBI_tax_id), "AD", NCBI_tax_id))`

Comment: Smooth solutions with grepl

Answer (score 0):

```
df$NCBI_tax_id <- gsub(x = df1$NCBI_tax_id,  # Which column to change?
                       pattern = "Adenoassociated.*",  # change from
                       replacement = "AD")  # change to
```